# Soap with wssecurity

Tags: c#, soap

What is the best/doable way to implement SOAP, ws-security in C#.
These are the required security tokes as per documentation
–
Required Security
Tokens
•Username Token (username, password, timestamp and nonce)
•User cert
•Server cert

In the past When I created a SAOP+ HTTP request, I used a stringbuider and appended the request

```
stringbuilder sb = new stringbuilder();
```

Then finally used HTTPWebrequest.create(url) and then a HTTP post.

Any hints on how to start would help. Can anyone point me to some tutorials. I have used a certificate generating tool to generate a certificate. 
I haven't really understood a good way to do this even after 3days of research and fiddling with certificates and web.configs

here's an example of a  sample request in the documentation

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/TEST/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
<wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:ReferenceList>
<xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
</xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>

<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>SQsTCAK6ZaVhojB8+Y.........</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: You should not be building SOAP by hand. Just use WCF. It will do all the work for you. If the "documentation" includes the WSDL, then just follow "[How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/)"

Comment: @JohnSaunders. Yes, I tried that...When I tried to add a service reference using the webservice url, It gave me fault error code.. which could be bcoz of authentication issues.. Then when I tried to add it using the wsdl, it gave me bunch of error.. custom tool error: So tried to uncheck Reuse Types.. but no use.. Also If I had used either of these, where would I use the certificate and how wuld i generate all the other CanonicalizationMethod , Signature info and the rest

Comment: You would specify the certificate either through configuration or in code. WCF would generate all signatures for you.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Do you have any examples.. or links I could look at... Its grt that WCF will generate all the signautures..

Comment: You should try again with add service reference and ask a question here if you still have problems.